# Start expressjs server when browser opens

Tags: express, webpack

I have a basic Expessjs server and can run it with `npm start`. I can also build it with `npm run build`. This way, `dist/main.js` file created. I want my expressjs server run when I open the index.html. However, below error happens when index.html is opened. I don't need es5 compatibility. So, not using babel.

Thanx

[image]

When I change to `target: ['web'],` 32 fallback error hapens like;

[image]

Is my use case reasonable? If so, how to do it?

Details are like these;

*src/server.js*

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
});

app.get("/api/ping", (request, response) => {
    console.log("❇️ Received GET request to /api/ping");
    response.json({ reply: "GET pong!" });
});

app.post("/api/ping", (request, response) => {
    console.log("❇️ Received POST request to /api/ping");
    response.json({ reply: "POST pong!" });
});

// Express port-switching logic
let port = 3001;

// Start the listener!
const listener = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("❇️ Express server is running on port", listener.address().port);
});
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "webpack-basic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": "true",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "node src/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    target: ['node'],
    entry: "./src/server.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "main.js",
    },
};
```

*dist/index.html*

```
<body>
    <div id="root" />
    <script src=" ./main.js "></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the reason you are trying to run a nodejs program in the browser?

Comment: I need to make an ssh connection to a network element. Will use ssh2 for this. Ssh2 can't be used just inside a react app. Needs to be used inside nodejs. I want to keep my ssh sessions on the clientside, not on the serverside. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could add an API endpoint in your nodejs app to create a ssh connection? You could return the output from the ssh command to the client side?

Answer (score 1):

No, your use case is not reasonable, unfortunately. You are trying to run a Nodejs server in the browser.

The other way works tho, you have to run the server so you can display the `index.html` file. You would need to add a new route handler to your `server.js` file to point all other request to the index.html file (or you can [use a template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)):

```
const path = require('path');
...

app.get("/api/ping", (request, response) => {
    console.log("❇️ Received GET request to /api/ping");
    response.json({ reply: "GET pong!" });
});

app.post("/api/ping", (request, response) => {
    console.log("❇️ Received POST request to /api/ping");
    response.json({ reply: "POST pong!" });
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

...
```

Comment: I know the use case sounds weird. However, I need to make an ssh connection to a network element. Will use ssh2 for this. Ssh2 can't be used just inside a react app. Needs to be used inside nodejs. I want to keep my ssh sessions on the clientside, not on the serverside. Any suggestion?